# Tensorflow: is there a way to build a weighted histogram without tf.bincount?

Tags: python, gpu, tensorflow

In my opinion the numpy function `bincount` is very useful and simple to use, so i naturally use the analogue function in TensorFlow. Recently i learned that unfortunately `tf.bincount` doesn't have GPU support (as you can read [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/11499)). Is there any other way to do weighted histograms, like in the example below, in TensorFlow **with** GPU and efficiently?

```
sess = tf.Session()

values = tf.random_uniform((1,50),10,20,dtype = tf.int32)
weights = tf.random_uniform((1,50),0,1,dtype = tf.float32)

counts = tf.bincount(values, weights = weights)

histogram = sess.run(counts)
print(histogram)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by [*ekelsen* on GitHub](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/11554#issuecomment-316767683), an efficient and GPU-supported alternative to `tf.bincount` is `tf.unsorted_segment_sum`.
As you can read in [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/unsorted_segment_sum), you can use the function with weights as `data`, values as `segments_ids`. The 3rd argument `num_segments` should be ≥ the size of the bincount returned histogram (if > you will have only zero elements after the last one of the previous histogram). In my example above it will be:

```
sess = tf.Session()

values = tf.random_uniform((1,50),10,20,dtype = tf.int32)
weights = tf.random_uniform((1,50),0,1,dtype = tf.float32)
bins = 50
counts = tf.unsorted_segment_sum(weights, values, bins)

histogram = sess.run(counts)
print(histogram)
```

and the output:

```
[ 0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          
  2.92621088  1.12118244  2.79792929  0.96016133  2.75781202  
  2.55233836  2.71923089  0.75750649  2.84039998  3.41356659  
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          
  0.          0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Any idea how to make it supporting batches?.